# Excel VBA - Loop to filter table for each value in column and paste in according worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, loops, copy, worksheet

I am trying to filter a table on the first worksheet ("Data") for each of the items that appear in a table on the second worksheet ("Hosts"), and then paste the filtered results in separate worksheets, each named after the corresponding item on the table.

My understanding of VBA is very basic and I have tried to put together a collage of codes from other users, but it doesn't seem to work properly for me:

- The first loop creates worksheets based on the items on the "Hosts" table, but for some reason it adds an extra sheet before the ones I need and calls it "Sheet1"
- The second loop simply doesn't work
- Are two loops really necessary, or is it possible to combine the two?

This is the code I have so far:

```
Sub test()
Dim AllData As Worksheet
Dim HostList As Worksheet
Dim DataRange As Range
Dim FilterColumn As Long

Set AllData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
Set HostList = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Hosts")
Set DataRange = AllData.Range(Range("A1"), Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlLastCell))

Dim HostValues As Range

For Each HostValues In HostList.ListObjects("Table1").Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
        On Error Resume Next
        ActiveSheet.Name = HostValues.Value
        If Err.Number = 1004 Then
            Debug.Print HostValues.Value & "already used as a sheet name"
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

Next HostValues

For Each HostValues In HostList.ListObjects("Table1").Range
    AllData.Activate
    FilterColumn = 18
    DataRange.AutoFilter Field:=FilterColumn, Criteria1:=HostValues
        DataRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy

    Sheets(HostValues.Text).Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("V:V"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess

    AllData.Activate
    Cells.AutoFilter
Next HostValues
End Sub
```

Some kind soul out there please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's quite a bit to do here, but I'll give it a shot.

> The first loop creates worksheets based on the items on the "Hosts" table, but for some reason it adds an extra sheet before the ones I need and calls it "Sheet1"

My guess here is that `Hosts` contains a duplicate entry or something is causing the sheet rename section to fail. I would check the debug window for that. Or change

```
Debug.Print HostValues.Value & "already used as a sheet name"
```

to

```
msgBox HostValues.Value & "already used as a sheet name"
```

That will make a popup happen, should make it easier to see when the error happens. Something else you can try, comment out the two `OnError` statements with a `'` single quote. Then when an error is raised you can hit debug and work through what the program is upset with.

> The second loop simply doesn't work

I'm not sure on this one. When you use a `For Each` many times changing the collection it is operating on will give you some sort of problem. You've asked the computer to do something for every cell in this column, and then you change the values of the column. That's just a guess.

> Are two loops really necessary, or is it possible to combine the two?

You can combine the two, after creating the sheet for the Host you can move its data over to it.

#### Notes

- The approach with filtering may be giving you undue complexity try writing a loop without the filters and checking if the Host has a sheet, if it does move the data. If it does not create it and move the data.
- You do not need the `With/End With` block at all.
- `On Error Resume Next` is dangerous. It has its uses, take a look at [this](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/errorhandling.htm) for more information or handling errors.

Godspeed.